# JSon validation error : unexpected character at line 1 column 1

Tags: json, validation

I can't figure out why my json does not pass validation on http://jsonlint.org/.

Here is a part of the json :

```
﻿{
"AIR_COMPRIME": [
    {
        "titre": "Compresseur 2000 à 3000 litres | R:1 | Fuel",
        "prix_1": "47,00 €",
        "prix_2": "84,00 €",
        "prix_3": "150,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Compresseur sur brouette 900 l/min | Super",
        "prix_1": "47,00 €",
        "prix_2": "84,00 €",
        "prix_3": "150,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Centrale hydraulique avec marteau 18 kgs | R=1 | Super",
        "prix_1": "62,00 €",
        "prix_2": "98,00 €",
        "prix_3": "150,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Marteaux piqueur 5 à 8 kgs | Avec un outil",
        "prix_1": "16,00 €",
        "prix_2": "25,00 €",
        "prix_3": "80,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Marteaux brise béton 10 à 15 kgs | Avec un outil",
        "prix_1": "18,00 €",
        "prix_2": "28,00 €",
        "prix_3": "80,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Décrouteur pneumatique | Avec un outil",
        "prix_1": "18,00 €",
        "prix_2": "28,00 €",
        "prix_3": "80,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Marteaux brise béton 20 à 25 kgs | Avec un outil",
        "prix_1": "23,00 €",
        "prix_2": "33,00 €",
        "prix_3": "80,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Sablon mural ou plafonnier",
        "prix_1": "16,00 €",
        "prix_2": "25,00 €",
        "prix_3": "80,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Sableuse mini max 10L | Sable en supplément",
        "prix_1": "40,00 €",
        "prix_2": "67,00 €",
        "prix_3": "150,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Sableuse 50 L pour sablage à sec | Sable en supplément",
        "prix_1": "67,00 €",
        "prix_2": "111,00 €",
        "prix_3": "150,00 €"
    },
    {
        "titre": "Sableuse 50 L pour sablage humide | Sable en supplément",
        "prix_1": "93,00 €",
        "prix_2": "146,00 €",
        "prix_3": "150,00 €"
    }
]
}
```

I get following error :

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I've read it could be some encoding problems, I've tried to reencode the file in UTF-8 but doesn't change anaything.

My first file which pass validation is in my opinion excatly the same and go through validation ... anay feedbak on this error would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Copy/pasting the code from your question passes the linter. You need to provide code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Cpoy/pasting in chrome gives me : Unexpected token and in firefox still the previous error ... can't give anything else since it gives me error !